# Show date picker when using prompt() method

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to show datepicker, in the prompt box when using prompt() method and if so how can I do it?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You'll have to implement your own modal dialog mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The window [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) is a feature of the OS and not something you can change. You would have to create your own dialog instead.